# clogit in R: original variable or demeaned?

Tags: r, logistic, fixed-effects-model, splines, clogit

[Conditional logistic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_choice#F._Logit_with_variables_that_vary_over_alternatives_.28also_called_conditional_logit.29) is a [fixed effects model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_effects_model). If you're modeling the dependent variable $y$, a glm fixed effect model doesn't actually model $y$. Instead, the glm fixed effect models measure $y-mean(y)$ for a particular group. I think that this is *not* the case for a conditional logistic regression. The coefficients of the regression can be interpreted in the space of $y$. Is that correct?

My particular situation:
I am running a conditional logit with [clogit](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/survival/html/clogit.html) in R, from the `survival` package. Are the coefficients returned to be interpreted in the space of $y$, or in the space of something like $y-mean(y)$?

Normally the difference isn't very relevant; one would interpret the coefficient roughly the same either way. However, in my case one of the independent variables is fitted as a spline. Specifically, it is a restricted cubic spline, as calculated from `rcspline.eval` in the [Hmisc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/Hmisc.pdf) package. `clogit` produces a coefficient for each knot of the spline, and in order to interpret the overall effect of the variable one needs to reconstruct the spline from the coefficients (using `rcspline.restate`). I want to make sure that I should be looking at the shape of this spline in the range of $y$ (which in my case is 0-100) or in the range of something like $y-mean(y)$ (in this case, $mean(y)$ is the same for all groups: 50). If it is the case that the space is shifted this will be particularly weird for a spline, because presumably the knots should also be shifted somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As nicely explained in [this](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/library/sg124.pdf) document:

> The exponentiated conditional logistic regression coefficients have
>   the same odds-ratio interpretation as ordinary logistic estimates.
>
> Conditional logistic regression differs from ordinary logistic
>   regression in that the data are divided into groups and, within each
>   group, the observed probability of positive outcome is either
>   predetermined due to the data construction (such as matched
>   case–control)  or  in  part  determined  because  of  unobserved 
>   differences  across  the  groups.  Thus,  the  likelihood  of  the 
>   data depends  on  the  conditional  probabilities—the  probability  of
>   the  observed  pattern  of  positive  and  negative  responses  within
>   group  conditional  on  that  number  of  positive  outcomes  being 
>   observed.  Terms  that  have  a  constant  within-group  effect  on 
>   the unconditional  probabilities—such  as  intercepts  and  variables 
>   that  do  not  vary—cancel  in  the  formation  of  these  conditional
>   probabilities and so remain unestimated.

In other words, the difference between conditional logit and regular logit regressions comes from how you estimate the probability of a positive outcome for a given observation, not from how you interpret odds ratios (i.e. the exponentiated coefficients). In the conditional logit model, the estimated probability of observing y_i=1 for a given observation is conditional to the number of 1s that are observed in a given group.

If you are interested in the equations that show how this conditional probability works, a simple starting point is the [Stata reference manual for clogit](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/rclogit.pdf).